# How does CNAME work for Google Apps for My Domain?

Tags: domains, subdomain, google-workspace

I recently got a domain and set it up with Google Apps including setting up sub-domains for the different services.

After set up the CNAME, all my subdomains point to `ghs.google.com`. I was wondering how this works with all subdomains pointing to the same site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser sends a request to Google's server with the `Host: yoursite.com` header.

Google looks up this hostname in a (very large) database mapping hostnames to websites, then serves the corresponding website.

This database includes App Engine apps, Google Apps aliases, BlogSpot blogs, and other things.

Comment: OK, but if that is the case, surely the header must be 'subdomain.mydomain.com` otherwise how would it know whether to look up a Blog or and App.

Comment: Try the live headers for firefox plugin and see whats being sent, but the process outline above is roughly how it works.

Comment: Thanks. Firefox is awesome. So I guess the Google servers must differentiate on the basis of the the Host name passed in the headers. Makes sense.